# В этом примере причастие или прилагательное?

Tags: грамматика, прилагательные, причастия

**Не/искушённый в таких делах человек.**

Слитно или раздельно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Неискушённый в таких делах человек.*** Пишется слитно.

Это прилагательное, которое можно заменить синонимом без НЕ. Например, малоопытный, малосведущий. Наличие зависимых слов здесь не влияет на написание НЕ.